# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get final cucumber.api.Scenario field cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition$ScenarioAdaptor.scenario

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

> Error while logging error -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not get final cucumber.api.Scenario field cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition$ScenarioAdaptor.scenario on cucumber.runner.Scenario
>
> Below is the code:
>
> ```
> private void logError(Scenario scenario) {
> try {
> Class clasz =     ClassUtils.getClass("cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition$ScenarioAdaptor");
> Field fieldScenario = FieldUtils.getField(clasz, "scenario", true);
> fieldScenario.setAccessible(true);
> Object objectScenario =  fieldScenario.get(scenario);
>
>             Field fieldStepResults = objectScenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("stepResults");
>             fieldStepResults.setAccessible(true);
>     
>             ArrayList<Result> results = (ArrayList<Result>) fieldStepResults.get(objectScenario);
>             for (Result result : results) {
>                 if (result.getError() != null) {
>                     System.out.println(String.format("Error Scenario: %s"+ scenario.getId())+ result.getError().getMessage());
>                 }
>             }
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             System.out.println("Error while logging error -> "+ e);
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> Can some one help me here to resolved this issue.
>
> Used the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
>             <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
>             <version>4.8.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>     
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
>             <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
>             <version>4.8.1</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>
> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
>             <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
>             <version>4.8.1</version>
>         </dependency>
> ```
>
> I am not able to update the cucumber version to v5 as i have some dependencies in v4. It would be a great help if anyone can help me in.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/10299604/frank-escobar